# Can dupe suggestions pay attention to question tags?

Tags: feature-request, asking

When creating a new question we all get the suggestions of similar or potentially dupes.

With this site in particular, going solely on question title can lead to false positives since we *can* have the same question for multiple different games and that would be just fine.

If a tag is available, can the "Questions with similar titles" take that into account?

Comment: A related suggestion from Meta Stack Exchange for [putting tags in the suggested dupes when they show up](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2031/please-show-the-tags-associated-with-each-question-listed-in-the-related-questi).

Comment: A *newer related suggestion from Meta Stack Exchange for... [well, you know](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/170056/please-show-tags-in-the-list-of-suggested-questions-that-may-already-have-your-a). Recently revived from new discussions.